# Is asking for review code and asking for better code allowed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, code-review-se

I have a problem and I don't want to ask before I try. So I try it first and my code works well but the problem is I'm not sure whether my code is good enough or not. such as maybe there is better solution, simpler function to solve my problem or my code is a bit complicated.

can I ask question something like that ?

here is my question and got downvote (and no reason why): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28123594/get-table-header-name-in-excel I also created title as search engine friendly as possible

Comment: There's a own SE site for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Ooh sorry I didn't know it before.. I'll ask again there or maybe administrator can move my question to there?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I already re-ask that question in code review site. what should i do to my old question? remove it or ... ?

Comment: As far I could spot it did have an answer, but no downvotes or upvotes on it. I'd delete it, yes.